# What are the "Globe" and "Park" in "Phyllis and Rosamond" by Virginia Woolf?

Tags: short-stories, virginia-woolf

I'm reading Virginia Woolf's short story "[Phyllis and Rosamond](https://archive.org/details/completeshorterf0000wool_z2p2/page/16/mode/2up)" and, well, here's the opening passage:

> In this very curious age, when we are beginning to require pictures of people, their minds and their coats, a faithful outline, drawn with no skill but veracity, may possibly have some value.
>
> Let each man, I heard it said the other day, write down the details of a day’s work; posterity will be as glad of the catalogue as we should be if we had such a record of how the door keeper at the Globe, and the man who kept the Park gates passed Saturday March 18th in the year of our Lord 1568.

I can't, for the life of me, figure out what Globe or Park she's talking about. I've googled everything but in vain. The Globe Theatre wasn't built till much later, and I think she might be referring to Hyde Park, but that wasn't opened to the public until 1617. In any case, I don't know how Hyde Park could be related to whatever Globe she's talking about.

Comment: As far as I can ascertain, the 18th March 1568 was a Thursday and not a Saturday, so perhaps she just didn't do a fact check for her first published work?

Comment: Thanks @Spagirl , that's the thought I'm leaning towards as well!

Comment: @Spagirl According to timeanddate.com, [18 March 1568](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=1568&country=9) was a Thursday in the UK, but if you calculated by hand and forgot to remove the [11 days lost](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=1752&country=9) in the switch from Julian to Gregorian, then you might conclude that 18 March 1568 was a Saturday. That's probably what happened here. Or ... she just didn't check at all.

Comment: @shoover It was the possibility of the 11 stolen days that made me go look it up!